# Are any Devotion feats worth taking without turn/rebuke undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

The optimizer in me instinctively didn't want to take Devotion feats without any turn attempts to fuel extra usages, since I'm not getting full use out of the feat.  However, I can't help wondering if some of them wouldn't be worth taking for just the one daily usage - like Travel, Trickery, or Animal for example.

To make this more concrete - are there any Devotion feats that are worth taking as a spellthief at level 3 for just the one daily usage?  (Only other feat so far is Weapon Finesse)

Comment: Added some additional info to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Knowledge Devotion is awesome, and doesn’t care about Turn Undead

Knowledge Devotion can be used at will; it does not reference or use turn undead in any way. It provides a minimum of +1 attack, +1 damage, but with fairly easy Knowledge checks, can produce larger bonuses. Dramatically better returns than the Weapon Focus *et al.* line, without requiring you to be a fighter, or tying you to a single weapon. A very solid feat.

## Travel Devotion is good enough to be worth a feat even 1/day

Travel Devotion gives you a minute’s worth of swift-action movement; that’s worth a feat. Of course, it gets *massively* better with more Turn Undead; a Cha of 12 nets you 3 minutes of swift-action movement per day, while a Cha of 16 (which, as a spellthief, you may actually have) gets you 4.

## Trickery Devotion, again, 1/day could be enough

Trickery Devotion is a bit tougher to use, but you burn Turn Undead uses *very* quickly getting more of it (since it uses 3 per use), so not having Turn Undead probably won’t slow you  down very much. And getting to make a duplicate of yourself for a minute/level each day is, well, very tricksy indeed.

## Law Devotion gives a hefty bonus for a minute/day

Like Trickery, Law uses 3 uses of Turn Undead per use of the devotion, which means you do not get dramatically more uses out of it by having Turn Undead. Each use gives you a pretty large bonus to attack or AC for a minute (+3 until 10th, then +5 until 15th, then +7). You need to hit if you’re going to steal anything.

## Animal Devotion, if you’re desperate

Animal Devotion gives flight in a feat. That is very rare. Without Turn Undead, you only get 1 minute/day, which sucks, but 1 minute/day is still an awful lot better than none. Also has some other solid uses, once you get yourself set up with a more permanent form of flight.

## Cleric dips are really strong!

Don’t ignore the possibility of just taking a level in (cloistered) cleric. You’d get all the devotion feats you want for free, plus Turn Undead to fuel them, plus a smattering of spells. Which, if you do go cloistered cleric, includes *identify* as a 1st-level divine spell – and *identify* doesn’t have an expensive material component when used as a divine spell. This is awesome.

#### Bonus Mention: Godsblood Spelltheft sounds thematically appropriate, is very useful

Godsblood Spelltheft is a feat introduced by [Class Chronicles: Factotums and Spellthieves](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111223109/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frcc/20070606), the same place we got Font of Inspiration from. It is somewhat specific to the Forgotten Realms, but it’s easy enough to fit into any campaign setting, either with a different list of gods and domains, or the same domains but for different reasons, or whatever. Point is, the feat allows you to be sure that, no matter what spell you steal, if it’s useless you can always use one of these domain spells. That’s worth a lot to a spellthief.

For the list of domains that you are eligible to choose, see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93640/4563).

Comment: Monsters, too, *love* the feats Travel Devotion and Animal Devotion--they're *so* much happier with those than the feats Alertness or Weapon Focus. Also, often overlooked is this *Complete Champion* erratum: "At the end of the section describing the 10th-level benefits [of the feat Trickery Devotion], a sentence should read, 'Phantom versions of your equipment do not have any of the magical or alchemical effects that your normal equipment has.'"

Comment: I think Law Devotion deserves a seat at this table, especially at high levels.

Comment: @Ernir Hmm, yeah, I suppose a minute of quite-large bonuses to attack is worth a feat.

Comment: I recommend, despite the attempt to help, *either* deleting the list of domains *or* finding a more reliable source? As is, multiple domains are repeated in the list (Knowledge *thrice!*), I can't find two of the listed domains (Deception and Mist), and it omits a bunch of Domains that would make the list more useful and comprehensive.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I made a separate question about it [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93640/4563) since I don’t really have time to research this right now. I’ve included this list as an answer to comment on/downvote as appropriate.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I lied, I did some of the research and came up with *a* list.

Comment: I only noticed the weirdness of your list because I had my handmade list on hand. However, putting it into a format suitable for posting took longer than I expected. Thank you, though, for alphabetizing the list of domains; that was maddening.